# How make a configure/makefiles from an C file?

Tags: programming, packaging, c, autotools

Hope this is not a stupid question. But here it goes...

Over the last month I have learned Programming in C and Gtk to a point where I have written a small program in C.

I would like to make a ubuntu package of my program. The project contains 3 glade files and 1 C file. I know that there is documentation on packaging ubuntu packages from a tar ball as per this question. [How to create deb installer from tarballs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14219/how-to-create-deb-installer-from-tarballs-closed)

But my question is how do I go from the 4 files to the tar ball state? I am not looking for the tar -cf ...

What I am looking for is a guide that will help me create configure / makefiles ect.

Comment: Please improve the question title, configure/makefiles are not related to the "ubuntu package" development process, that is part of the regular source building process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source building for C applications is most commonly managed with the autotools utilites, using autotools is not trivial, better check a tutorial:
http://markuskimius.wikidot.com/programming:tut:autotools

Answer (score 2):

To create configure/makefiles you must use the GNU autotools. Follow the tutorial at http://www.lrde.epita.fr/~adl/autotools.html

The resulting Makefile will be able to create the tarball for you.

To make a .deb file containing your application, follow the guide at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Complete

I think that what you are looking for :)