# How do I fetch a specific package version from a repository?

Tags: apt, ppa

Adding a PPA then running `apt-get update` to fetch seems to only fetch the latest version from that PPA, but I would like to install a specific version.

Eg: I'm adding the `ondrej/php5-5.6` ppa. After an update, `apt-cache policy php5` shows me that the available versions are:

- `5.6.9+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+2`
- `5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.9`
- `5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4`

A few days ago, the latest version from the PPA was `5.6.8+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+4`, but now it has updated. This means that I can't run an `apt-get install` and install the particular version I want.

Is this possible using apt?

Comment: Which PPA are you using?

Comment: For clarity, I'm looking to be able to fetch particular versions from PPA's in general, not trying to avoid new releases of PHP. This just happens to be the example in front of me

Comment: @Wilf I'm adding ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6, using add-apt-repository

Comment: Use launchpad to find the actually find the package.  The note the name and use that to download via terminal

Comment: @Virusboy, thanks for the tip - I investigated and think I found the solution I was after

Answer (score 3):

It seems as though using `apt-get install php5=5.6.*` to match the version number solves the problem.

Looking on launchpad, version 4.6.8 no longer exists, only version 4.6.9 exists.

Similarly, the `ppa:git-core/ppa` PPA on launchpad only contains versions 2.4.2 and 2.3.7. It seems as though the latest patch release of each minor version is kept.

Using this meaning I can tie the install to a particular minor release, while still receiving patch updates.

Comment: This 'solves the problem' only in such that the repository has to have that version.  If you have multiple PPAs that's one thing, but if the version available in the repos is higher than you have downloaded/cached on your system, it's not going to work.  (There are no transactional updates in apt repos)

Answer (score 2):

You can only install the latest version from a PPA, as old versions are deleted when new versions of a package are built and published in a PPA.

Answer (score 1):

@Dobey answer seems to be the best solution in your situation. Though if you installed a package from a specific PPA what you can do is to mark that package when it's installed so to keep that version. For example run:

```
sudo apt-mark hold packagename
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sometimes get old versions, depending on the source. For the most part, when a package is updated, it replaces the previous updated version (some repos keep the first version for that release, until the release goes End Of Life). This also depends on whether newer versions include security updates, or are [no longer supported 'upstream'](http://php.net/supported-versions.php) (where the package came from).

If the version you want to install is still in the repository, you can use [this syntax](https://askubuntu.com/a/92021/178596) to install the package:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2=2.2.20-1ubuntu1
```

*If is not available from the repo you are using, you may be able to get the package from elsewhere.*

With [the PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5-5.6/+packages?batch=75&memo=75&start=75) you seem to be using, you can currently get version 5.6.9. But there is [another PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5/+packages?batch=75&memo=75&start=75) by the author, from which you can get version 5.5.25. *(There is also [this one](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5-oldstable) with 5.4.41, but only really for 12.04)*

There are also third-party sites that often have old (and sometimes newer) versions. For Ubuntu, [Ubuntu Updates](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/pm/php5) (there other sites as well - e.g. for Fedora etc there is [rpmfind](http://rpmfind.net) *(yes, RPMs.... - you can use alien (see below), or get the src.rpm and use the stuff in that to build something usable in non-RPM systems :D*).

If all else fails, you can get try to a get a source version of the version you want (for PHP, see [here](http://php.net/releases/#4.4.9)), and then make the packages from that. This you can [build and install directly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file), or build deb package(s) out of it and install those.

You can also use [alien](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RPM/AlienHowto) to install packages not in the deb format ([this seems to include tar.gz](https://askubuntu.com/a/14220/178596)).