# Auto compile service on for Ubuntu packages?

Tags: package-management, compiling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)
>   [create a .deb Package from scripts or binaries](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27715/create-a-deb-package-from-scripts-or-binaries)

Is there any service provided by Ubuntu , to automatically compile source to binary deb packages , and for multi-architecture ?

Comment: @ajmitch , i think that's totally different , i'm the developer , not people who need to use my package ...

Comment: I think you're looking for bzr recipes in PPA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is provided by Launchpad, called [Personal Package Archives](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA). This lets you built packages for any supported Ubuntu release, and for multiple architectures.