# GWT (Google Web Toolkit) App through USC (Ubuntu Software Center)

Tags: software-center, java, google, javascript

Is it possible do deploy google web toolkit (GWT) apps through the UBUNTU software center?
I never deployed any application through the UBUNTU software center (newbie). So if yes, is there someone who can give me a short tutorial for handling this? I have nice ideas to spread the world with innovative apps and want to use the USC for this ;)

Comment: by deploy u mean u want ur apps to be available in USC? If thats the case first of all any app can't be available through USC unless canonical decide to have it in repository. Another thing you can do is start ur own ppa containing ur apps and if user add that ppa then they will see ur app in USC. Furthermore app should be in the form of .deb (my assumption) to be able to add to ppa.

Comment: Ok THX for the fast answer! I have good skills in Java and C# (.net) and want do develop nice GUIs that run on any platform (Ubuntu, Win, Mac, and mobiles like Android, IOS). I also want to make my products available through USC. What's the best technology in your opinion for me to use? I thought that GWT generates nice GUIs with Java => Java-script. I know that GWT is generally used for WEB but i also made nice desktop-applications with GWT and this technology is very nice to use for developing distributed systems. But with GWT i can't make a .dep-file...

Comment: possible duplicate of [create a .deb Package from scripts or binaries](http://askubuntu.com/questions/27715/create-a-deb-package-from-scripts-or-binaries)

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I am able to answer my own question with YES!

I can create a Web-Application with e.g, Google Web Toolkit! After I have to bundle it in an archive file (.tar.gz, .zip, etc)! For further information see: http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/my-apps-packages/

The Web-App can be stored locally on the System. The only thing to to, is to create the application launcher with the following command: `Exec=xdg-open <path to the local html-File on the System>`

Thats it!