# Python dependencies in Debian packages

Tags: package-management, python, dependencies, debian

I created my first Debian package today by following the accepted answer at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90764/how-do-i-create-a-deb-package-for-a-single-python-script) AskUbuntu question. Everything went fine, and it installed properly afterwards. However, my script is written in `python` and depends on the `BeautifulSoup` library.

My plan is to send the package to a friend who I am nearly certain does not have `pip` or the like installed. What is the best way to attach such a dependency to my package or ensure that it is installed along with the package?

Comment: if you're rolling new packages, you really should depend on and import bs4 not beautifulsoup

Comment: For Python dependencies that are not already packaged in Debian/Ubuntu I recommend this approach: http://askubuntu.com/questions/327543/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BeautifulSoup package is in Ubuntu repositories as `python-beautifulsoup`. You need to specify that your package depends on it.

In the [answer you linked to](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90764/how-do-i-create-a-deb-package-for-a-single-python-script), have a look at `debian/control` file - there is `Depends:` section where you can specify package dependencies.