# How can a Debian package install Python modules from PyPI

Tags: package-management, python, debian

This question tries to complement [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233483/python-dependencies-in-debian-packages) .
I have a python app which uses third party modules from PyPI. I want to package my app into a debian package, but don't know how to handle python dependencies which are not in debian/ubuntu repositories(packed as debian packages too)

**Solution #1:**
build the modules from PyPI right into my debian package.

**Solution #2:**
create debian packages for all PyPI modules I need using **stdeb** and add them to debian/ubuntu repositories.

I actually need a *Solution #3* because I want to install PyPI dependencies when I install my debian package, preferably into a virtualenv!

What would be **Solution #3**? Do I need to tweak *DEBIAN/preinst*  maintainer script?

Comment: Can you describe why you need to create a Debian package? Does your Python app need non-Python resources?

Comment: @Jonathan I want users to be able to install my app from Ubuntu Software Center. I think I need a *.deb for that. My Python app doesn't need non-Python resources, just third-party python modules.

Comment: @Jonathan Debian packages are the standard installation method in Ubuntu. One can easily distribute a `.deb` file, or setup a private repository, or a PPA in Launchpad.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I've spoken with some maintainers at the Debian IRC channel [irc://irc.debian.org#debian-mentors](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianMentorsFaq#What_other_resources_are_there_for_new_and_prospective_Developers.3F), asking for the exact same thing, and the general consensus was:

**Solution #1:**

Integrating dependencies in your package by copying their source files over as a single codebase is *very* frowned upon. It would defeat the purpose of a packaging system that handles dependencies, updates, versioning, etc.

**Solution #3:**

Downloading non-debian packages on-the-fly when installing a binary (`.deb`) is a *serious* security risk, definitely a no-no. You wouldn't even be able to *inspect*  the dependencies by extracting the `deb`, because they are downloaded and installed at install time. It's an approach that completely bypass the repositories system. No concerned user would be happy with a package that, behind the scenes (and as `root`, remember!), downloads additional untrusted software from untrusted sources. Yes, that would require fiddling with `DEBIAN/postinst` (or `preinst`) and issuing a `wget` (or, in your case, `pip install`), and that is the approach taken by Flash, Oracle Java, Steam and others. But that is proprietary, closed source software, so their security is none anyway.

**Solution #1.5:**

You didn't mention it, but you could integrate the dependencies only at *build time*, ie, in the *source* package (the `.orig.tar.gz`, `.debian.tar.gz`, `.dsc` triad), by downloading from PyPi when creating the "binary" package (the `.deb`). The instructions for the `pip install` would go into `debian/rules` (notice the lowercase `debian`, as opposed to the binary package), and would be executed when you issue `debuild` or `dpkg-buildpackage`.

This is a middle-ground between #1 and #3. It mitigates (but not solve!) some of the issues of #3: at least you can inspect the final product, and the `.deb` would not require internet access at install time. All the risks and burdens are transferred from final user to the package maintainer. But, has the same problems as #1, as it bypasses most of the packaging system infrastructure. Afterall, handling dependencies (versions, updates, requirements, conflicts) is why `dpkg`/`apt`was created in the first place! :)

**Solution #2:**

The *One True Right Way™*. You create debian packages for your dependencies, list them as requirements in your package, and ship all the `.debs` or source packages.

From there, you have a number of options:

- [Submit](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/upload.en.html) the source packages, both your software and its dependencies, for inclusion to Debian. If accepted, they would be automatically available to all Debian users, including all derivatives like Ubuntu.
- Upload the source packages to [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/), thus creating a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas) that any Ubuntu user (and its derivatives like Linux Mint) could easily add and install
- Host your own debian repository in your website, that users from any Debian-based system could add to their `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and use the `apt` infrastructure to download, install and keep updated, (like the above!)
- Host the `.deb` files for direct download and install. No `apt` or automatic updates involved thought.

As for *how* to package your PyPi dependencies (and your python software too!), there are a number of tools and references that make the process easy:

- [stdeb](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=stdeb&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all), as you mentioned. Oldie and goodie.
- [Pybuild](https://wiki.debian.org/Python/Pybuild), a new, amazing tool from Debian that supersedes `stdeb`.

And many useful references:

- [Style Guide for Packaging Python Libraries](https://wiki.debian.org/Python/LibraryStyleGuide)
- [Debian Python Policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/python-policy/)

Need help? Check those out:

- [Debian Mentors FAQ](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianMentorsFaq)
- [Python Packaging Team](https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/PythonAppsPackagingTeam)

Answer (score 4):

There is `pypi2deb` to get a package from pypi and make it into a deb package.

Comment: Unfortunately at the moment it doesn't look actively developed anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I think you just need to add the relevant command line code to the postinst script in the .deb package.  Found in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62534/adding-post-deb-install-scripts), more details at the [official debian guide](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use [dh-virtualenv](https://github.com/spotify/dh-virtualenv) which will package a pip project into a Debian package with virtualenv (packed with a all dependencies).

```
sudo apt install dh-make dh-virtualenv
```

You'll need a Python project with `setup.py` (and `pyproject.toml` or `requirements.txt`). Inside that project generate `debian/` directory e.g. using:

```
dh_make --indep --createorig --native --packagename mypackage_0.1.0
```

Remove example files:

```
rm debian/*.ex debian/*.EX debian/README.*
```

Update build dependencies in `debian/control`

```
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 11), python3, dh-virtualenv (>= 1.0)
```

Edit `debian/rules`:

```
%:
      dh $@ --with python-virtualenv
```

Finally try building the package with:

```
( deactivate ; dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -b )
```

See [documenetation](https://dh-virtualenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) for more details.