# How do I package a Python script for Ubuntu?

Tags: python, packaging

I have a Python 3.2 script that I'd like to package for Ubuntu and Debian. I've certainly looked for documentation but I wasn't sure that I was getting the latest and greatest/easiest methods.

If someone with enough knowledge could please point me to the most recent guide on how to do this, it would be very useful to me.

Additionally, given a bit of what I have seen I might need a setup.py file too? If so I need to learn about that too.

Answer (score 5):

The Ubuntu developer portal has a very complete [Packaging Guide](http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/).

There is also a tool, [Quickly](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/tools/quickly/), designed to help new developers hack and package their applications easily and... quickly. This tool will also help you creating the `setup.py` script.

Finally, take a look at how to [get started](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/) at Ubuntu application development.

Answer (score 0):

You could use debreate. A GUI tool to make .deb files. you can get it [here](http://debreate.sourceforge.net/).
You could also look into ST Alfas answer in [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90764/how-do-i-create-a-deb-package-for-a-single-python-script). Hope this helps! :)