# How to turn a .py file into a .deb package using quickly?

Tags: python, quickly, packaging, deb

We have made a `.py` file that controls brightness of the screen. It has a [GUI](https://github.com/apandada1/Brightness/blob/master/img/screenshot-1.png?raw=true) with slider for controlling and runs when it is double clicked after marking it as executable.

But we want to make a `.deb` package with it for easily distributing. Is there any way to do it with Quickly? If not, then what are the other ways?

We also want to associate it with an icon.

The project we are trying to debianize is [here](https://github.com/lordamit/Brightness).

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for atleast one of your questions. I removed the second question.

Comment: @CallmeV The code is in Github. https://github.com/lordamit/Brightness

Comment: @CallmeV I have manually created a [.deb](https://www.dropbox.com/s/43luqyos1vkep39/brightness.deb) package manually but it shows package is poor quality. I made it using [this tutorial](http://askubuntu.com/a/91563/124466)

Comment: adding a readme and a man page should fix that.

Comment: it's in the debian packaging guide.  i'm a little busy to do all the googling for you, but i assure you...it's all there

Answer (score 1):

[FPM](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm) is a great tool for packaging not only deb but other formats too like rpm.

Answer (score 0):

If you check out the wiki for [Quickly](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Quickly). It's the third step under "How to get started":

```
quickly package
```

Comment: You cannot turn a .py file into .deb just by quickly package.

Comment: I guess I assumed you're using quickly to create your project. The "using quickly" in your title and question implies that's what you're using to help create your python project. If you're not using quickly from start to finish for your project, then I'm afraid you can't package it with quickly.

Comment: I want to know if there is any way to port it to quickly.