# How to prepare my program for Launchpad

Tags: apt, package-management, packaging, deb, launchpad

I wrote Python program and made DEB (https://github.com/CyberTailor/vk-stats/releases/download/0.9/vk-stats_0.9-1_all.deb).

Now, I want to upload this package to Launchpad, but it doesn't accept DEB packages. I know, that I should made *source.changes* file, but how?

[Working directory](https://dropmefiles.com/EIK2c)

Comment: You may also find my earlier answer helpful: http://askubuntu.com/a/339488/3940

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of building a binary package you indeed need to build a source package and let the launchpad ppa build binaries for you.

To create the `source.changes` file, just issue the following command:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -S
```

From the `dpkg-buildpackage` man page:

```
   -S     Specifies a source-only build, no binary  packages  need  to  be
          made.  Passed to dpkg-genchanges.
```