# How to create a deb package for a python3 script?

Tags: command-line, packaging, deb, python3

I have one Python file, main.py. I would like to be able to make a .deb package from it, and then be able to run main.py by typing the package name from the terminal. It is written in Python 3, so the package name should run:

```
python3 main.py
```

The only dependency I know of is python3.

I have tried creating a deb with a dependency of python3, and then running `python3 packagename`, but I get:

```
/usr/bin/python3: can't find '__main__' module in 'packagename'
```

Trying to use Debreate for package creation fails to open with :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/debreate", line 12, in <module>
    import wx, sys, os, debreate, db, language, shutil
  File "/usr/share/debreate/debreate.py", line 23, in <module>
    import os, sys, wx.lib.dialogs, db, webbrowser, language, shutil, subprocess
  File "/usr/share/debreate/db.py", line 5, in <module>
    import wx, wx.combo, wx.lib.mixins.listctrl as LC, os, sys, language
ImportError: No module named combo
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a deb package for a single python script?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/90764/how-do-i-create-a-deb-package-for-a-single-python-script)

Comment: Aditya: all answers used python2. I need it to use python3.

Comment: I also need to be able to run the package from the command line. I tried this already but after installation i get command not found

Comment: I have left a comment below the post of @andrewsomething to update it for Python 3. In the meantime please [edit] your question to include what you have already tried and what are the results/error that you get.

Comment: have you tried [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm)? FUNDAMENTAL PRINCIPLE: IF FPM IS NOT HELPING YOU MAKE PACKAGES EASILY, THEN THERE IS A BUG IN FPM.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Creating a .deb for a python3 script is very simple, and only requires a few changes in debian/rules and debian/control if you're familiar with python2 packaging.

In a nutshell:

1. Create the package source dir

   ```
   mkdir myscript-0.1
   ```
2. Copy your python3 script (or the sample script below) to the source dir

   ```
   cp ~/myscript myscript-0.1
   cd myscript-0.1
   ```

   *Sample script:*

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/python3

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       print("Hello world")
   ```
3. Create the packaging skeleton (debian/*)

   ```
   dh_make -s --indep --createorig
   ```
4. Remove the example files

   ```
   rm debian/*.ex debian/*.EX debian/README.*
   ```
5. Edit debian/control

   Replace its content with the following text:

   ```
   Source: myscript
   Section: utils
   Priority: optional
   Maintainer: Name, 
   Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9), python3
   Standards-Version: 3.9.5
   X-Python3-Version: >= 3.2

   Package: myscript
   Architecture: all
   Depends: ${misc:Depends}, ${python3:Depends}
   Description: insert up to 60 chars description
    insert long description, indented with spaces
   ```
6. debian/install must contain the script to install as well as the target directory

   ```
   echo myscript usr/bin > debian/install
   ```
7. Edit debian/rules

   Replace its content with the following text:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/make -f

   %:
       dh $@ --with=python3
   ```

   **Note:** it's a TAB before `dh $@`, not four spaces!
8. Build the package

   ```
   debuild -us -uc
   ```

You  will get a few Lintian warnings/errors but your package is ready to be used:

```
../myscript_0.1-1_all.deb
```

Comment: Do you know how to include translations (PO/POT) into the DEB file?  I think there's a command needed within debian/rules but I've never been able to figure it out.

Comment: @Bernmeister, Please create a new question about translation support. I'd prefer to keep this one as simple as possible. Thanks

Comment: `dh_make: error: argument -i/--indep: not allowed with argument -s/--single`

Answer (score 0):

For the error you encounter in **debreate**,

```
sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8
```

source: [source of above solution](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1922419)