# How can I convert a ready Python project into DEB

Tags: python, packaging

I am using package guide of Ubuntu (http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html), but I am stuck in compilation stage. I can compile .deb using

```
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc -us
```

but, `bzr dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc -us` or `bzr buildeb -rfakeroot -uc -us` gives not found error. Also on launchpad, the project build always fails.

Comment: Just checking, did you install the `bzr-builddeb` package?

Comment: Yes, it is installed and using the newest version

Answer (score 2):

In [an answer to a slightly different question](https://askubuntu.com/a/512850/449), I mention `stdeb`. If your project is packaged on PyPI you can:

```
# enable proposed repos first!
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-stdeb
sudo pypi-install xxxx
```

(where xxxx is the PyPI name)

If it's packaged (for setuptools, etc) but not on PyPI you can still use `py2dsc` (which ships with `stdeb`) which can convert a `.tgz` of your project into a deb file.

You can read more about this with more example on [`stdeb`'s PyPI page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stdeb).

If it's not packaged or on PyPI, then yeah, you've got the "proper" route ahead, though you can side-step a lot of the process with [this wonderful answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/91616/449). You don't need to recommit everything into BZR and upload it just to build a deb.

Comment: It is packaged and has a setup.py. I can install it via pip for example. Once I upload it into launchpad, will it start building itself?

Comment: The [wonderful answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/91616/449) covers python2. In this [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/399552/how-to-create-a-deb-package-for-a-python3-script) you'll find the python3 version