# How to compile a SH file so it can be uploaded to PPA Launchpad

Tags: ppa, compiling, launchpad, sh

I want to make a few installation scripts via .SH files, and then upload them to http://launchpad.net? How would I do that?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/90764/how-do-i-create-a-deb-package-for-a-single-python-script might be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you don't *compile* a `.sh` file.  What you need to do is create a Debian package for your program to upload to Launchpad PPAs.

The [packaging guide](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/) details all the steps in creating a package.  You ultimately have to create the package from scratch and follow the guide to make sure you meet all the requirements.  There may be simpler how-tos for everything [in this question on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345/what-is-the-simplest-debian-packaging-guide), it has my two (VERY BASIC) how-tos, which will walk you through creation of the package, but it does violate a lot of the packaging requirements, including manpages, etc.

**However.**  As someone who has made administration scripts myself, it may be more prudent to just provide users the `.sh` scripts and run them themselves from wherever they want, rather than install them as if they were an executable, either in a `bzr` repository or a `git` repository somewhere.