# how to create a debian package to install a python module

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, python, deb

I came across this answer: [How do I create a deb package for a single python script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90764/how-do-i-create-a-deb-package-for-a-single-python-script)

Which is extremely helpful and well detailed.  I have everything except the install file.  In that post the user is installing a single .py file to /usr/bin.  I need to install a module to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

How should my install file be different?

Answer (score 1):

In the `debian/install` file, add this line (or only use this line, if there aren't any others in there):

```
moduleFileName /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

You basically use the same line format for each file (or directory):

```
filename /path/to/destination/
```

Comment: forgive my ignorance but how does it know to copy the __init__.py and *.py.  Say the module is called calc and I have calc.py and __init__.py and utils.py?

Comment: You can write a line for each file, if they have to go to different destinations, or you could write *.py if they can all go into the same directory.