# How to run python script installed after converting to .deb?

Tags: package-management, bash, python, scripts, deb

I installed a python script using the instruction of @STAlfas' answer in [How do I create deb package for only single python script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90764/how-do-i-create-a-deb-package-for-a-single-python-script)

It worked correctly, (I think so). But I don't know how to run it. I tried to find it out, but I couldn't. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Not sure what you did, but is the script installed? and if so, where?

Comment: I followed the instructions given [here] (http://askubuntu.com/questions/90764/how-do-i-create-a-deb-package-for-a-single-python-script) in the answer of @STAlfas. I created .deb file and moved it to home folder. I installed it using "dpkg -i mypyscript.deb". But now I run "mypyscript" it shows "command not found".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you program is supposed to be called as CLI command, you want to make an entry point using setuptools: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17401381/debianzing-a-python-program-to-get-a-deb

If it's used as a library, you can use the 'import' statement in python to use the code.

Comment: You're right, it's installed as a python-module. But I wanted it to act like a linux command-line software.

Comment: Then the instructions in the link should be exactly what you need. Have you had any luck in trying it out?