# Is it possible to package Python app into snap packages?

Tags: packaging, snap

Can Python (or anything other than QML/web apps) be turned into snap packages instead of .deb packages as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90764/how-do-i-create-a-deb-package-for-a-single-python-script)?

Is there any detailed documentation available?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Oh certainly-- [here](https://docs.snapcraft.io/build-snaps/python) is a detailed walkthrough of how (and why) to create a Python snap.

Comment: Hint: you need to use the python3 plugin to get all the dependencies

Comment: Or the python2 plugin, depending on version required of course :) .

Comment: Yes. I used python3 as an example

Comment: The 'start here' link gives a 404 (page no longer there).

Comment: Thanks @arielf, fixed. There are better docs for it nowadays anyway.