# How to create a deb package from a directory of python project which also need of other package/command to work?

Tags: server, package-management, python

How do I create a deb package for distribution from a directory of python project on Ubuntu 16.04?

I did search for it and the closest I found is [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90764/how-do-i-create-a-deb-package-for-a-single-python-script/91616#91616)

What I have right now is a directory consists of a REST server written in python. I want to convert this directory to a deb package so the person who get the package can easily installed on their computer to run the REST server.

The detail of directory structure is like below

```
server
  |--api-----------------
  |                |--__init__.py
  |--main.py       |--v1---------------
  |                                |---__init__.py
  |--__init__.py                   |---resources-------
                                                |
                                                |---a.py
                                                |---b.py
                                                |---tasks.py
```

Normally, I run this server as `python main.py` after running a `celery` worker by typing `celery -A server.api.v1.resources.tasks worker --loglevel=INFO`

What I want to ask now is there a way to convert this project into `deb` packages for distribution? Since I also use `celery` worker for supporting the server, is it possible to convert this directory together with the command for the worker? What I mean here is that when someone run the `deb` package on his/her ubuntu computer, the server can run together with the worker.

Answer (score 1):

Try [fpm](http://fpm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Installing from the docs cited:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ruby ruby-dev rubygems build-essential 
% sudo gem install --no-ri --no-rdoc fpm
```

After fpm is installed:

```
$ cd server
$ fpm -s python -t deb .
```

Some customization for your particular situation. You could add "celery" to `install_requires` of `setup.py`.  Also fpm options `--python-install-bin` and `--python-install-lib` might be used to specify where binary and library files should go. Further documentation of the `python` source is located [as well](https://fpm.readthedocs.io/en/v1.9.3/source/python.html).

You might also need to create some sort of custom script to kick this off.

Comment: you might add information on how OP could use `fpm` to add deb package dependencies, so they would automatically be installed alongside the python project: `-d, --depends DEPENDENCY      A dependency. This flag can be specified multiple times. Value is usually in the form of: -d 'name' or -d 'name > version'`

Comment: also I'm not experienced with package type `python`. if this would not work, OP could use `-s dir`