# How to create your own Linux package from scratch?

Tags: command-line, package-management, scripts, gnome-shell, packaging

How do you create your own package in Linux, just like `cd`, `ls`, or any third party package?

All I know is how to create a `.sh` file, write a script in it and execute it using:

```
bash file_name
```

But in addition to that I want to understand in more depth. Please explain the complete steps from downloading using `apt-get` to how to run it.

Comment: The easy part is to create the application, the tool. The difficult part is to get it accepted as a linux package (as part of an officially supported repository). A simpler alternative for Ubuntu is to upload it to a PPA at Launchpad or provide the tool in some [other] kind of container via for example GitHub.

Comment: This link might be a good starting point for what you want: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300540/how-to-duplicate-a-ubuntu-system-for-distribution

Comment: Please unlearn the *"create a .sh file and write your script in it and execute it using "bash file_name"* paradigm - script files should use an appropriate [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) to indicate which interpreter should run them, rather than having the user specify an interpreter on the command line.

Answer (score 7):

I am assuming you want to write a new program and distribute it as a Debian package in Ubuntu.

Suppose you have the bash script, `hello`, and you have marked it as executable

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello World"
```

1. Now [create](https://askubuntu.com/a/91616/124466) a Debian package which will place this `hello` file in `/usr/bin`. The linked answer is about a single python script, but it works the same way with a bash script. Once installed, it can be run from the terminal with:

   ```
   username@computer~$ hello
   ```
2. [Upload](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/Uploading) the Debian source to a Launchpad PPA, so that users can add it to their system, and subsequently download it with `apt`.
3. You can later [submit it](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/upload.en.html) to Debian's repositories, so that it can be directly installed in Ubuntu and other derivatives of Debian (although I don't know if Debian maintainers allow simple bash scripts to be added to their repositories. But you can put any program in your own Launchpad PPA).