# How to make a setup File for a python3 application in Ubuntu?

Tags: python

I make a game called Pong with Python3 and Turtle.

Now I want to make a setup file so that I can share my game with others.

I watched [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tM65X1i6kOM) and tried what he does in that video but I am on Ubuntu20.04 and it hasn't worked.

I want to make a file that installs all my files where that "setup" file is, My folder has
[these files in it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYVgm.png)

So please tell me how can I make a setup file for my Pong game that I have made with Python3 Turtle module.

Comment: With a single python file, you really don't need setup.py. You can execute `python3 Pong.py` to run it. You can also easily package it into a .deb package and share it. See https://askubuntu.com/a/91616/124466

Comment: i don't understant that, That is too hard for me, Please tell me how can i make a setup.py file for my game :(

Comment: https://the-hitchhikers-guide-to-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/