# How can I make a .deb file from a bash script?

Tags: installation, bash, deb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [create a .deb Package from scripts or binaries](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27715/create-a-deb-package-from-scripts-or-binaries)

I've made [a bash script](http://pastebin.com/SdXs3Pw5) and stored it in `/usr/local/bin`. In the future, I'd like to get this bash script in `/usr/local/bin` again by just installing a `.deb` file. How can I get this done?

Comment: pastebin the bash script and i'll consider doing a walkthrough packaging it and upping it to ppa.  just a thought *no promises*

Comment: Sounds awesome. I don't think that a PPA is really necessary though, as it's just a really simple script. Updated the question to include a link to the bash script.

Comment: Looks like the duplicate answers my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You would need to make a package from scratch using [the packaging guide](http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/) to create the package.  You'd have to make sure the package is compliant with Lintian as well, all this is outlined in that guide.  Either that, or have someone package it and put it in a PPA for you.