# How to package a simple bash script

Tags: bash, packaging

The below bash script was written in ~10 sec, but packaging it would take me hours of skimming through [big walls of text](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/) so I ask my self if there is an easy way out there that I don't know about.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Hello World"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could check this answer: [create a .deb Package from scripts or binaries](https://askubuntu.com/a/27731/12218)
The answer provides a quick guide in 8 simple steps.

As an extra you could check a similar procedure for Python scripts: 
[Create deb package for Python source and upload it to ppa at Launchpad](http://wiki.iccode.net/python/create_deb_package_from_python_source_and_upload_it_to_ppa_at_launchpad)

Comment: Finally a quick & dirty way to create deb's for a simple shell script. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

**This answer was originally copied from the question it was in. It was placed here to retain the QA format.**

- First we need to install these packages: `sudo apt-get install dh-make devscripts`
- Copy the script into an editor and save it as `hello`

  ```
  chmod u+x hello
  mkdir hello-0.1
  cp hello hello-0.1/

  cd hello-0.1/
  dh_make -s --indep --createorig
  grep -v makefile debian/rules > debian/rules.new
  mv debian/rules.new debian/rules
  echo hello usr/bin > debian/install
  echo "1.0" > debian/source/format
  rm debian/*.ex
  debuild -us -uc
  cd ..
  sudo dpkg -i hello_0.1-1_all.deb
  ```

Now entering `hello` into the Terminal prints 'Hello World'.

Comment: Note: `dh_make` disallows using `-s` AND `--indep`. Use `--indep` only.