# Why is nvm not packaged in the ubuntu repositories?

Tags: apt, package-management, nodejs

```
$ sudo apt-get install nvm
…
E: Unable to locate package nvm
```

Installation instructions usually involve running random scripts from GitHub (`curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.11.1/install.sh | bash`), instead of using the well-known `apt-get`, `yum` or equivalent for other distributions.

Why isn't nvm packaged for Ubuntu?

I guess there must be a technical reason since nvm is a common piece of software, like a licensing issue or something like this, so I'm curious to know why it cannot be packaged. I searched online for a package and for a reason, but didn't get any useful result.

Comment: Never heard of nvm. Feel free to become a package maintainer if you so desire, make a ppa

Comment: For packaging see https://askubuntu.com/questions/279686/how-to-package-a-simple-bash-script

Answer (score 5):

As per https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/761, it seems that the author(s) of `nvm` (the Node.JS Version Manager) strongly opposes to packaging `nvm` using distribution's standard package management tools, and prefer to roll their own solution.

This most likely didn't motivate people to package the tool.

Comment: Upstream does not want to package, and I don't blame them to be honest. I think it would be rather trivial to package if you were interested, a ppa would be trivial to maintain.

Comment: I do blame them, it means that instead of doing a standard `sudo apt install … … a dozen pieces of software … … …`, if everyone does this then what would take 1 minute to install a dozen applications becomes on average 10+ minutes of searching online for a package that doesn't exist and trying to find the installation steps, for each piece of software :-( . Welcome back to the Windows era of search + download on dubious sites + click next next next next next.

Comment: I'd like to second that: I do blame them as well.  In addition to the point made above, getting packages from a distribution is a thousand times *safer* than downloading from the internet, where any number of intermediate hops may be compromised.  A system like apt, yum, dnf or whatever will reliably check digital signatures.  Piping a script through bash won't.