# How can I install nvm in Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: software-installation, nodejs, 19.04

How can I install Node Version Manager in Ubuntu 19.04?

Comment: did you try `wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install a Specific Version of Node on Ubuntu Server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/957439/how-to-install-a-specific-version-of-node-on-ubuntu-server) As usual the OP will probably not read it and say it doesn't answer it, but it actually does.

Comment: @karel: I don't see the duplication. The OP is asking how to install nvm, while the question you refer to specifically says "I don't want to use nvm for this."

Comment: Since you insist the specific quote that I was referring to is *Users can switch between versions of Node.js at any time without needing to involve additional tools like nvm (Node Version Manager), for example: `sudo snap refresh node --channel=10/stable`*. Unfortunately disagreements sometimes do arise, but the logic that I was referring to is that installing  nvm is no longer necessary with the node snap package.

Comment: @karel Your'e right though and good to know about that way as a snap package, but i need to use nvm for my progress

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `nvm` is not packaged in the Ubuntu repositories, so you cannot install it with `apt` (see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/935216/why-is-nvm-not-packaged-in-the-ubuntu-repositories)).

To install it simply run either the cURL or Wget command in the [installation instructions](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installation-and-update) at `nvm` GitHub repository.