# How do I create a deb package for a precompiled files?

Tags: package-management, deb, packaging, rpm

I know how to package `rpm` for RHEL, but have little experience of `deb` packaging.

I'd like to package other OS's library and headers for making cross-compiler, so there won't need any compilation process. However, `deb` packaging process forces to write some kind of `Makefile`.

How can I make a deb package for a precompiled files? I won't distribute it except for coworkers, so I dont' need all kind of complex debian packaging rules.

Here is for my `rpm` `.spec` file. It is almost trivial..

```
%define os some-os
%define rootname sysroot-%{os}
%global debug_package %{nil}
Name: sysroot-some-os
License: UNLICENSED
Version: 0.1
Release: 1
Source: sysroot-some-os.tar.bz2
Summary: Sysroot from some os

BuildArch: noarch
BuildRequires: bzip2

%description
Sysroot from some os

%prep
%setup -q -n %{rootname}

%install
mkdir -p ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}/opt/cross/%{os}/sysroot
cp -r * ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}/opt/cross/%{os}/sysroot
chmod -R -x ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}/opt/cross/%{os}/sysroot

%files
/opt/cross/%{os}/sysroot

%changelog
blabla..
```

EDIT:

maybe one can think `debian/install` solve this problem, but as you can see, this package has a lot of files and writing every file is not a good idea. (Look at `.spec` file.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create a .deb Package from scripts or binaries](http://askubuntu.com/questions/27715/create-a-deb-package-from-scripts-or-binaries)

Comment: @muru No, I dont' think so. 1) I have a archive file that has to be extracted properly 2) I want to make working debian build script equivalent to my `rpm` `.spec` file, however that answers dont.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can create *Debian Binary Package* directly

All you need is

1. `packagename/DEBIAN/control` file, example:

   ```
   Package: linuxstatus
   Version: 1.1-1
   Section: base
   Priority: optional
   Architecture: all
   Depends: bash (>= 2.05a-11), textutils (>= 2.0-12), awk, procps (>= \
   1:2.0.7-8), sed (>= 3.02-8), grep (>= 2.4.2-3), coreutils (>= 5.0-5)
   Maintainer: Chr. Clemens Lee <clemens@kclee.de>
   Description: Linux system information
    This script provides a broad overview of different
    system aspects.
   ```
2. Your files in same structure of installation in `packagename` folder
3. Run `cd ..; dpkg-deb --build packagename`

**Reference:** [Debian Binary Package Building HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Debian-Binary-Package-Building-HOWTO/)

Comment: This made a package, but when I installed the package, no files were installed.

Comment: @fadedbee, Could you please create new question and share the building log.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I succeeded with: https://gist.github.com/stbuehler/4125579  Sorry - it was a keyring package, so I can't really post it publicly.