# Build a package native debian package

Tags: 18.04

I want to build a native debian package to install the software on the server. What would be the best approach to build a package for ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: https://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/   though if you want to make available for others, PPAs are by far the easiest in my experience

Comment: Does this answer your question? [create a .deb Package from scripts or binaries](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27715/create-a-deb-package-from-scripts-or-binaries) (Also https://askubuntu.com/questions/71510/how-do-i-create-a-ppa if you want to make a PPA)

Comment: I followed the process and i see the following errors.:dpkg-deb: error: failed to make temporary file (control member): Permission denied @guiverc