# how to convert an application to .deb

Tags: gnome, application-development, deb, appmenu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simplest Debian Packaging Guide?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345/simplest-debian-packaging-guide)

I have downloaded an application from here
http://projects.gnome.org/postr/
and extracted it on my desktop 
it runs fine if I go to the downloaded directory and run as

```
sudo ./postr
```

I want to add this to context menu,application menu how can I do so.This is not a .deb  file how can I convert it to .deb?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do it yourself... It's in the repositories.
You can install it from the software centre.

If you still want the `deb`-file, run `sudo apt-get download postr` from a terminal.

Comment: no I want the latest version which I downloaded I know it is in repos but I want to use the one I downloaded

Comment: but the latest version is already in the repositories (0.12.4): http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=postr - http://ftp.acc.umu.se/pub/GNOME/sources/postr/ -- Unless you downloaded the source from the git repository?

Comment: Isn't this the latest version? http://packages.debian.org/sid/postr If it is, just use that one :p