# What is the correct way to create your own packages for local installation?

Tags: apt, package-management, packaging

I am running an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server. I currently have an issue where one of my used packages has an annoying bug. Instead of removing it and just building it from source, I want to integrate it into Ubuntus/Debians package management.

Coming from ArchLinux we did this by copying the original PKGBUILD and changing it in such a way that it compiles the *new* package. This is a very simple process but it informs the package manager about this package even though it is in no local repositories.

Is there a similar way for Ubuntu/Debian? Can I easily base my package on the outdated Ubuntu version and install this package instead of the original repository one?

*Note*: The concerning software is libvirt (I need 0.9.13 at least, 12.04 runs 0.9.8) and while I would appreciate a solution for this particular package in the comments, I am looking for a more general solution for such problems should they arise in the future.

Contrary to questions [How can I manually assemble my own package “the hard way”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111288/how-can-i-manually-assemble-my-own-package-the-hard-way) and [What is the simplest Debian Packaging Guide?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111288/how-can-i-manually-assemble-my-own-package-the-hard-way) I am not interested in creating a *new* package but instead using existing resources and update them to a newer version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get my software into Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16446/how-to-get-my-software-into-ubuntu)

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but updated libvirt is in the Cloud Archive: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/CloudArchive

Comment: You can always download the older package version from wherever, and then install it by hand, without repackaging everything.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen he wants to fix a bug locally no submitting a new package to Ubuntu.

Comment: @Braiam Thanks, I suppose I misunderstood "I want to integrate it into Ubuntus/Debians package management."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would download the source and the build dependencies for the Ubuntu version first:

```
apt-get install dpkg-dev
apt-get build-dep <package>
apt-get source <package>
```

The unmodified, upstream source the Ubuntu version is based on will be in a file called <pkg>_<ver>.orig.tar.gz (compression scheme may vary) - I would decompress this to one directory (let's call it "dir A"), then download the source to the bug-fixed version into another directory ("dir B"), and then generate a patch for what's changed:

```
diff -Nur <dirA> <dirB> >/tmp/upgrade.patch
```

Then change to the directory where apt-get source decompressed the modified Ubuntu version, and apply the patch

```
patch -p1 </tmp/upgrade.patch
```

Assuming there weren't many changes between the two upstream versions, and they didn't conflict with any of the Ubuntu packager's changes, this should work. Then edit debian/changelog in the Ubuntu package to give it a new version number, and dpkg-buildpackage should build you a custom version..

Answer (score 1):

Just to toot my own horn, I have creating a solution for this exact circumstance. You can have a Debian package downloaded, unpacked, built, and reinstalled in 2 or 3 commands.

It is a shell script [debtool](https://github.com/brbsix/debtool) and is available on GitHub via the aforementioned link.

Building Debian packages from source can be cumbersome, especially on a daily driver that you don't necessarily want to muddle up with numerous build dependencies and the like.

Assuming *libvirt* is available via sources, run the following command:

```
debtool --download --unpack libvirt
```

The above command just downloaded the *libvirt_0.9.8_all.deb* file and unpacked it into the directory *libvirt_0.9.8_all*.

Alternatively, you can unpack the version of *libvirt* that is currently installed on your system:

```
debtool --unpack libvirt
```

At this point you should make all of your changes to the files in the directory. You will also likely want to bump up the package's version number (i.e. 0.9.8-custom1) located in *./libvirt_0.9.8_all/DEBIAN/control*.

Now build the package by running the following command:

```
debtool --build ./libvirt_0.9.8_all
```

Your finished package is now in the current directory as *libvirt_0.9.8-custom1_all.deb*.

You can quickly reinstall this package by running `debtool --reinst ./libvirt_0.9.8-custom1_all.deb` or alternatively `debtool --build --reinst ./libvirt_0.9.8_all` to build and reinstall in one fell swoop.

## Etcetera

You can do a couple of other related tasks with *debtool* as well.

### Show Available Versions

If there are several versions of a package available in the repositories, you can list them as follows:

```
debtool --show zsh
```

The above command will return the following:

```
zsh 5.0.5-4ubuntu1~ubuntu14.04.1 amd64
zsh 5.0.2-3ubuntu6 amd64
```

If you'd like to download the packages manually then you can use the `--show-format` option.

```
debtool --show --show-format zsh
```

Will return the following:

```
apt-get download zsh=5.0.5-4ubuntu1~ubuntu14.04.1 -a=amd64
apt-get download zsh=5.0.2-3ubuntu6 -a=amd64
```

### Download Debian Archives

You can download the most recent version of a package as follows:

```
debtool --download zsh
```

You can download a specific version as follows:

```
debtool --download zsh=5.0.2-3ubuntu6
```

### Unpacking Packages

You can unpack a package on your hard drive:

```
debtool --unpack package.deb
```

You can also unpack a package that is currently installed on your system:

```
debtool --unpack package
```

If you have made changes to any of the installed files, they will be incorporated as well. This is perfect if you want to work with a package that is no longer available from sources or if you want to incorporate pre-existing fixes into a 'patched' deb.

Comment: Depending upon how local is meant by local, and given you may want stable software, the process should be extendable to a custom repository (not a ppa).  Note how this is done for many rebadged distros such as Zorin, Mint, Peppermint etc.