# Help me update the old rtirq-init script for Ubuntu?

Tags: packaging, debian, source-code, rpm

rtirq-init is an important package for low latency audio system configuration.

The current version has a 2021 version and regular updates:
https://www.rncbc.org/drupal/node/2163

**Problem 1.** the version in the repositories is chronically outdated, from 2015(!):
https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=rtirq&searchon=names

**Problem 2.** RNC releases the source code and .rpm's, but they follow different naming conventions than the version found in the Ubuntu repositories (Debian/Ubuntu appends *-init). I have tried building from source in the past and the difference in naming conventions broke system dependencies. So there is some sort of modification/configuration or dependency reconciliation that I need to do for other apps that depend on "rtirq-init" and not "rtirq"

**Problem 3.** I would like to provide an updated package version for the community, but have never done this before.

**Questions:**

1. What are the instructions for building the script for Ubuntu from source?
2. How do I follow the correct naming conventions so the package doesn't break existing dependencies? Specifically, in Ubuntu/Debian it is packaged as rtirq-init, not rtirq. Will this workflow resolve this issue: https://askubuntu.com/a/411799/672975 as well as #1 above?
3. Where or to whom do I submit it once it is built? Is this question relevant: https://askubuntu.com/a/16456/672975 What would be the most preferable course/workflow in this particular circumstance?

Comment: I'm not a *dev*, but I know the easiest place to *build* packages for your own testing (which is done before packages get submitted & built for Ubuntu packaging) is via PPA, which yes is covered in your linked question (I've done that myself, for changes that went into Ubuntu packages).   Ubuntu follows it's upstream (Debian) standards for the most part in naming conventions, so I'd try and follow that, but as you're building the package, you can decide what standard you'll follow (esp. if you don't go beyond PPA; but note: I didn't see your issue with your problem 2).

Comment: PPAs are 3rd party sources, meaning there is no review unless you set it up for yourself (or your team). It's why everyone should check the trustworthiness, quality & source for any PPA before adding them to their system. There is more involved in getting it into Ubuntu repositories, but again your linked question is a good start.

Comment: Ahh, RNC replied, he has a PPA here: https://launchpad.net/~rncbc. I am modifying my question about why packages get obsolete and what to do about it if there isn't a question already (will search). Thank you!

Comment: @ethan Would you put that as an answer, it does solve the original issue of the post. So others who may take same path as you can find the solution quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, RNC replied, he has a PPA here: [https://launchpad.net/~rncbc](https://launchpad.net/%7Erncbc).