# Creating Debian Package For Qt app

Tags: packaging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simplest Debian Packaging Guide?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345/simplest-debian-packaging-guide)

I'm writing an IDE in C++ using Qt for the GUI and Qt Creator as an IDE. I have seen many tutorials about the Debian packaging system but I am still not sure I get it.

My program is not ready yet so I don't want to submit it to developer.ubuntu.com for someone to package it, but I want to do it to easily distribute a few copies.

I use Git for VCS and my code is hosted at Github.

I want to know if I should be keeping my code directory in a / related structure. Like: /usr/bin for the binaries and so on. This is for making the packaging process as easy as it can be. Do I need to modify the Makefile to put the binaries in /usr/bin or something like that? I do not have much experience with gnu make.

Is it a problem to host my code at Github? because I prefer it to launchpad and algo prefer Git to bazaar.

Also, can someone explain how to do the packaging process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your source code doesn't need to match the installed layout. However the build system (Make / whatever you use) should install everything that's needed. And if a [DESTDIR](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/DESTDIR.html) variable is provided, it should prefix that to the installation paths.

No, it's not a problem to host on github. If you want [daily builds](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/SourceBuilds), you'll need to set up an automatic import into bzr on Launchpad, though.

If you're going through developer.ubuntu.com you don't need to worry about the packaging. They'll take care of it.