# Team Viewer on Ubuntu! Is it running through wine?

Tags: package-management, wine, teamviewer

I recently downloaded Team Viewer on my Ubuntu system, so my question is:

1. Does it run through `wine`?
2. And if yes, why is this a `.deb` file?
3. Is it possible to make `.deb` files but running with `wine`?

**Edit:** When I launched it for first time wine configuration showed up. Is it necessary to post a screen-shot for that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.deb` is a Debian Package which you can install in Ubuntu via Software Centre. It's native for GNU/Linux systems. On the contrary if you can lay your hands on a Windows version of Team Viewer, it can work through `wine`, mostly as **silver**. Check the details in WineHQ applications [database](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=5956).

**[edit]**
Yes, you can create a `.deb` package which runs an application using WINE. Every `.deb` binary package consists of at least three files:

1. `debian-binary` (description text file)
2. `control.tar.gz` (installation, post-installation and pre-removal scripts)
3. `data.tar.gz` (precompiled app and it's resources)

Installation scripts from *control* can copy any structure of files and folders from *data* including preconfigured WINEPREFIX, also a specific WINE version and all of it's dependencies can be embeded along with a post-installation script that creates menu shortcuts with proper environment variables.

Comment: Please try to understand what i am saying and then answer!Thanks!

Comment: Please ask one question at a time and make it clear. It is uncommon for `.deb` packages to use `wine`. However, it's just a package, so you need to ask whomever prepared it. Screen shot would help.

Answer (score 13):

> Does it run through wine?

yes

> why is this a .deb file ?

To easily install in debian based systems

> Is it possible to make .deb files but running with wine

YES , deb is the extension of the Debian software package format and the most often used name for such binary packages.?
To learn about debian packaging use this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345/simplest-debian-packaging-guide)

TeamViewer for Linux is based upon the Windows version using wine. Additionally, `/opt/teamviewer/teamviewer/$tv_ver/bin/teamviewer` contains links to a wrapper of a Windows executable:

```
export TV_BINDIR=/opt/teamviewer/teamviewer/$tv_ver/bin
exec "$TV_BINDIR"/wrapper "c:\Program Files\TeamViewer\Version$tv_ver\TeamViewer.exe" "$@"
```

Comment: Well, firstly does not run as it runs in windows, so the team viewer homepage should warn about wine etc. Secondly, what am I asking is if it is possible for me to make .deb files that install a program and then improve the wine compatibility of this program!?Is that possible?

Comment: it is prepacked with wine as in the case of picasa for linux ,So it is difficult to configure it

Comment: ok, is there any difference between installing  the windows version `.exe` file with wine and installing from `.deb` file?What is the main reason for making a difference? Can we produce better performance in windows apps with making them `.deb`?

Comment: No, `.deb`s are just packaging. They are friendlier on the users, and easier to uninstall.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. `TeamViewer`, like many other apps with  Windows-using developers, works through WINE.

Answer (score 0):

1. It can run with wine if it Windows executable file. That's, if you are using TeamView meant for Windows OS.
2. The .deb file can be run as direct installation in Linux. Probably, you downloaded the one for Ubuntu architecture. And, to run it simply double-click on the downloaded Teamview .ded file and install it from the Ubuntu Software Center where it directs you to.
3. I don't think .ded file can be run by wine. Most files with .exe run with wine. **Wine simply allows windows native applications to run in Linux**. So .ded won't run with it.

*I hope that helps!*

Comment: Unfortunately you are wrong, even if you download .deb file of TeamViewer - it just a wine wrapper over windows executable. At least this is correct for TeamViewer 10.