# teamviewer is not launching normally?

Tags: teamviewer

first of all I am new to Ubuntu but not for Linux and this is my first question or problem to be asked..
     and thank you guys in advance and i know all kind of these maybe asked and solved before, but i couldn't find something worked with me..
*note: i tried to execute it with root permission and it worked but i think it kind of dangerous.. so i want something normal

so when i run teamviewer normally it doesn't launch ! it shows me this

```
user@user:~$ teamviewer

Init...
XRandRWait: No value set. Using default.
XRandRWait: Started by user.
Checking setup...
chmod: changing permissions of '/home/user/.config/teamviewer': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of '/home/user/.local/share/teamviewer11/logfiles': Operation not permitted
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/user/.local/share/teamviewer11/dosdevices’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/user/.local/share/teamviewer11/.tweak’: Permission denied
wine: /home/user/.local/share/teamviewer11 is not owned by you
wine: /home/user/.local/share/teamviewer11 is not owned by you
```

Comment: Did you install `wine` as superuser? What happens when you run teamviewer as superuser: `sudo teamviewer`?

Comment: Why use wine? Here is teamvier for Linux https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux/

Comment: @PatrickNegus .. im not sure if wine is a superuser.. how do i know? .. and this what happens when i run teamviewer as superuser                  Init...
 *** TeamViewer can not be executed with sudo! ***
 Either use your normal user account without sudo
 or use a the real root account to log in to your desktop (not recommended!).

Comment: @MarkKirby .. i did not use     wine. i just launched it normally , and i did downloaded teamviewer from the same link u added

Comment: @MarkKirby I guess its packages for Linux but runs with Wine? http://askubuntu.com/questions/125153/team-viewer-on-ubuntu-is-it-running-through-wine

Comment: the thing is why does it work with `root` permission and does not work normally