# any basic app packaging guide for a newbie?

Tags: application-development, packaging, launchpad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simplest Debian Packaging Guide?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345/simplest-debian-packaging-guide)

i've made an app using wxpython, i have some .py files and some icons, how can i package it for uploading it to launchpad??

i've already set a ppa and it seems like i need to organize my files before packaging, i mean the debian file structure needed to make a tar.gz source package and how to upload it... i've read some guides (that have an already made tar.gz source package) but as this is my first app i do not understand most of the things...

any help?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a misunderstanding of what a .deb is.  The .tar.gz is the source code that is partly used in the source package, but not the source package for the deb itself.  Start by reading the [Packaging Guide](http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/), it should be a good starting point for you.

Comment: those are the guides i saw before, i'm asking for the file structure of the package, ie: i know the licence file goes on the root of the package, where goes the other files?? mainly the .py files and icons...

Comment: try using the basic guide, or examining other packages that are already built for their structure.  There is no one predetermined file structure, except that debian/ has to exist in the root, as well as a few other files (read the complete guide for in depth details)