# Is there any finished tutorial on how to develop and package unity web apps?

Tags: webapps

I want to create unity web-app for my new website.So,is there any up to the mark tutorial.I've read Ubuntu's official tutorial on this topic but that is not even complete.I've developed the code but don't know how to package the code

Comment: I found this tutorial:http://quickmediasolutions.com/blog/9/using-the-unity-web-api
This is quite nice but still dont know how to compile ".js" file I've created.I did "make" but that didn't do anything. :(

Answer (score 1):

Actually packaging a webapp isn't really different from packaging any other application. Take a look at resources [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345/what-is-the-simplest-debian-packaging-guide) and especially at existing integrations, e.g. [LinkedIn](https://code.launchpad.net/~webapps/unity-webapps-linkedin/trunk), [Feedly](https://github.com/eudennis/unity-webapps-feedly) and (shameless plug) [This Is My Jam](https://github.com/jnv/unity-webapps-thisismyjam).

Basically, you need `debian/` directory with at least the following files ([see the guide for details](http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/debian-dir-overview.html)):

- `control` with basic description for package manager (see [example](https://github.com/jnv/unity-webapps-thisismyjam/blob/master/debian/control)) Three keys are important for webapps in particular: `XB-Ubuntu-Webapps-Includes`, `XB-Ubuntu-Webapps-Name` and `XB-Ubuntu-Webapps-Domain`.
- `compat`
- `copyright`
- `install` specifies which files should be installed where
- `rules`
- `changelog` specifies the resulting version of the package and must follow a very specific format; can be managed using e.g. `dch` command

You can generate these files using e.g. `dh_make` command or just copy the `debian` directory from other webapps project and change package names, filenames, and domains.

Once you have the files in place, you should be able to generate package using e.g. `dpkg-buildpackage` command (from the `dpkg-dev` package). The resulting package is generated in the parent directory.

If you are using version control such as Git or Bazaar, take a look at [git-buildpackage](http://honk.sigxcpu.org/projects/git-buildpackage/manual-html/gbp.html) or [bzr-builddeb](https://launchpad.net/bzr-builddeb) respectively (both available in Ubuntu repository). I've found especially the `git dch` command useful for maintaining the changelog. There's a nice [HowTo on packaging with Git and uploading to PPA](http://blog.gantrithor.com/post/10300791891/debianize-github-projects-and-upload-to-ubuntu-ppa-1).

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at this link: http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/webapps/ seeing it's the official guide.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no information on how to create a package for the webapp. Documentation covers only webapps APIs.