# Convert .jar to .deb package

Tags: java, packaging

My project is to develop an installer which is an executable for Windows, Mac and Ubuntu. The executables on Windows, Mac and Ubuntu are `.exe`, .app and .deb respectively. So, I converted my .jar file to a `.exe` file on Windows using a software called launch4j. And on MAC I used a software called Jar-Bundler to convert my jar in to .app file. I want to know if there is any specific software on Ubuntu to convert my jar file in to a `.deb` file.

Comment: Ya .But I want it to be converted to an executable probably .deb file which is my requirement.For example on windows I used launch4j software to convert the .jar file to .exe file and on mac I used Jar-Bundler software to convert .jar to .app file.

Comment: Ok then consider editing your question to clarify what you are asking. On a side note, why do you want to make an installer for a java program ? One of the strong side about this language is that it is cross platform. If you keep your jar file, it could be run on either windows, ubuntu, or OSX, without any modification

Comment: I would say that your question mainly refers to packaging: having a jar file is just an element of the package. So, consider using "packaging" keyword for looking into this site, for example: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345/what-is-the-simplest-debian-packaging-guide

Comment: Apparently your are mixing some concept, at least on the Ubuntu side : a .deb find IS NOT an executable, this is a package possibily CONTAINING some files, some of them could be executable files under Ubuntu. The purpose of the .deb file is to allow easy distribution, installation and update of an application. Usually you can execute the code contained into a .jar file by doing `java -jar <yourjarfile> [name of the main java class]`.

Answer (score 3):

you can create a DEB from .jar file.

You have to add following code to your pom.xml file

```
<build>
    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>some-lib</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>deb-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <description>A test project</description>
              <maintainer>Tim OBrien &lt;tobrien@discursive.com&gt;</maintainer>
              <section>libs</section>
              <priority>optional</priority>     
              <architecture>all</architecture>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>deb</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

and after that running

`mvn package`

will gives your a .DEB file.

For more information you must read this : http://mojo.codehaus.org/deb-maven-plugin/using-deb.html

Comment: This link doesn't work for me anymore