# How to create a installer package of my software made in Code Blocks

Tags: 14.10, packaging, c++, code-blocks

I am an amateur developer, I'm using Ubuntu for like 1 month or so and I want to know how can I create an installer package form my Code Blocks C++ generated `release` file..

Comment: What kind of "installer package" are you talking about? The term is a bit generic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the simplest Debian Packaging Guide?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1345/what-is-the-simplest-debian-packaging-guide)

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of linux software install systems, so narrowing it down the two you might want to most look at are the .deb packages and source packages.
For Ubuntu's .deb format see http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html

That set of instructions depends on the traditional source distribution, a real under taking all truth be told.  Skim over http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html paying the most attention to the Configuration section.  Then this blog post https://robots.thoughtbot.com/the-magic-behind-configure-make-make-install will get you primmed on using autotools, which you may have to install. `sudo apt-get install automake` should give enough to fallow the directions on the blog post.

A 3rd format worth mentioning is the rpm format for Fedora/Red Hat Linux, but it would involve another Linux installation (or virtual machine).

Now a location to distribute the project from is the next major consideration. https://www.github.com is the current source distribution center most people favor.

congratulations on having a project you want to share,and good luck.