# How can I make a .deb package of Kdenlive from source in github?

Tags: deb, github, kdenlive

I'm trying to install Kdenlive from https://github.com/KDE/kdenlive. From looking Online, it seems the best way is to build a .deb package from the source and install it with the created package. But, how exactly do I go about making a .deb package from source from github?

Comment: it is possible to make a deb file but it is not quite easy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the simplest Debian Packaging Guide?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1345/what-is-the-simplest-debian-packaging-guide)

Comment: read this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30303/how-to-create-a-deb-file-manually

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You aren't building a deb from source here. You can read the documentation provided **on the link you posted**, but I will summarize here. The commands you will have to do will be as follows:

```
git clone https://www.github.com/KDE/kdenlive
cd kdenlive
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/bin
make -j4
sudo make install
```

This will:

- Gather the source files
- Set up a build environment
- Tell the system where to install (In this case, /usr/bin so that it can be called with just `kdenlive`)
- Build the source into binary
- Copy the binary into the installation path so that it can be called.

If, however, you really do want to build a `.deb` file, you can do most of this process the same. However, before you begin, start by running:

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
```

Then, follow the same procedure as above. **However**, replace:

```
sudo make install
```

With:

```
sudo checkinstall
```

The `checkinstall` application monitors what was made and installed, and compiles a .deb file accordingly.

Comment: If you don't want to keep the source files around after building, you can do `rm -r kdenlive` to delete them.

Comment: -1 This doesn't answer the question how to create a Debian package from the source code.

Comment: @DavidFoerster However, it does answer the question of "How can I install this from source?" The main question here was "How can I get this installed on my system?". The user had misinterpreted information and **thought** that building into a deb is the easiest way. I can modify to include building into a deb. EDIT: Fixed.

Comment: This is a fine answer, I would suggest maybe explaining more that even though this would work, this is not the proper way to build a real "deb".

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about `checkinstall`.  Nifty.

Comment: Thanks, all. Turns out I needed quite a few development packages in order to compile the software, but once I did, everything you suggested worked like a breeze!

Comment: Ok, I'm fine with the added explanation of why OP is apparently mistaken. Downvote reversed. +1