# Compiling/Installing squid with SSL_BUMP

Tags: compiling, deb, squid

My understanding is Ubuntu repository does not contain squid configured/compiled with SSL_BUMP. So I did download the sources and compiled the sources. No issues so far.

I would like to install the compiled binary on a different box and want to set it up like Ubuntu installation will do. That is to say, use the service command to start/stop squid and all the files in standard locations

Can I just replace newly compiled binary on target box if the version installed by Ubuntu apt-get command is same as the one I have compiled.

If that is not possible, do I need to copy all the files from install directory to target machine/appropriate directory? For example /etc to target machine/etc? How do I setup service command in this case?

Does the installation embed the installation directory name somewhere? If my install directory is different than standard one, will it cause any problems after copying?

Comment: Is your "different" box Ubuntu too or something completely different? If so and if you want to be 100% clean you should learn how to create a package so that you can install it on the other box.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek, it's ubuntu. Only difference would be where compiled is a desktop and destination is server. Both on 16.04

Comment: This may help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345/what-is-the-simplest-debian-packaging-guide