# Error in building debian package for ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

Hi I'm getting following error while building the package. Could anyone help me with this.

```
dpkg-deb: building package 'patrol' in '../tsom-patrol_0.1-1_all.deb'.
dpkg-deb: error: failed to make temporary file (control member): Permission denied
dh_builddeb: dpkg-deb --build debian/tsom-patrol .. returned exit code 2
dh_builddeb: Aborting due to earlier error
debian/rules:18: recipe for target 'binary' failed
make: *** [binary] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary subprocess returned exit status 2
debuild: fatal error at line 1152:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -us -uc -ui failed
```

Comment: Much more details are needed.

Comment: What are the more details you require regarding this?

Comment: Where did you get the source? How are you building? I see that there is some permission error that stops the build. There may be lots of reasons for it.

Comment: The source is just a tar file. My script extracts the tar file and runs the installation command. So i'm trying to build a deb package for that operation.

Comment: either your script is wrong, or the source has wrong permissions. How can anyone guess?

Comment: I copied my script in the `preinst` section. Is that the right way to do?

Comment: It depends on what the script is doing. But normally if the script unpacks the tar, it is not done this way.

Comment: Is there any way i can communicate with you?

Comment: You can [edit] your question and add the details on what you are doing. Then someone can answer the question.

Comment: Do you suggest any instructions to build a native debian package.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345/what-is-the-simplest-debian-packaging-guide